# Problems using my struct as a return type

Tags: c++, struct

I am building a templated class "myTree" that includes a private struct "myNode". I also have a private function "findNode" which I would like to return a myNode*. However, when I try and define the "findNode" I am getting 5 errors saying that seem to stem from the first error which says that I am missing a semicolon in between "myNode" and the "*".

Here is the basic code:

```
template <size_t N, typename ElemType>
class myTree {
public:
  //...
private:
  struct myNode{
    //...
  };
  myNode* findNode(const otherClass<N>& key);
};

template <size_t N, typename ElemType>
myNode* myTree<N, ElemType>::findNode(const otherClass<N>& key) {
  return 0;
}
```

I tried changing the return type to void and the errors disappeared, meaning I assume that there is something wrong with the way I am using my struct.

The errors are:
1) Syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
2) missing type specifier - int assumed
3) 'N' undeclared identifier
4) 'ElemType' undeclared identifier
5) 'N' undeclared identifier

These all point to the function declaration line ( myNode* myTree::findNode(const otherClass& key) { ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

myNode is an inner class and needs to be qualified in a return type:

```
template <size_t N, typename ElemType>
typename myTree<N,ElemType>::myNode*
myTree<N, ElemType>::findNode(const otherClass<N>& key)
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response :)  Could you tell me why then for a different method with a void return type but "myNode *" in the parameters I did not need to qualify myNode *?  The function declaration is as follows `template <size_t N, typename ElemType> void myTree<N, ElemType>::freeChildren(myNode* current) { ...`

Comment: When the arguments of a member function are parsed, it is clear that a function is parsed and which class the function is a member of. So you need to qualify only return values, but not arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You need a semicolon after

```
  myNode* findNode(const otherClass<N>& key);
```

Comment: whoops had that in the actual code, forgot to type it. Editing, thanks lol